# Next Button to trigger Css Animation's

Tags: jquery, css, animation, sequence

I have a click through of animations within a website.

At the moment I have everything working as planned, however there is a usability issue.

I have set the animations to be activated once the `div` box has been `clicked`. 
Where everything falls apart is when the user doesn't click directly onto the `div`.

Take a look at this example I've created, take note that if you don't click on the circle it runs into problems. — https://jsfiddle.net/ym2f50pq/11/

What Im curious to know is, if it is possible to add one 'next' button that will activate each animation one after the other.

**HTML** looks something like this:

```
<div class="z1 animation-1" style="background-image:url('name_of_image.jpeg')"></div>
<div class="z2 animation-2" style="background-image:url('name_of_image.jpeg')"></div>
<div class="z3 animation-3" style="background-image:url('name_of_image.jpeg')"></div>
<div class="z4 animation-4" style="background-image:url('name_of_image.jpeg')"></div>
```

**CSS** looks something like this:

```
.z1{ 
  z-index:99;
}
.z2{ 
  z-index:98;
}
.z3{ 
   z-index:97;
}
.z4{ 
  z-index:96;
}

.animation-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.is-open-animation-1 {
  animation: animation_1 2s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
@keyframes animation_1 {
  from {
     transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
  $('.animation-1').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('is-open-animation-1').one(animation.keyframes, function (e) {
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });
```

Would I do this by adding an `id` eg. `id='01'` and somehow using that to determine which animation goes next?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can easily be done by assigning an ID to each animation, e.g. `animation-id`, and then firing the `.click()` event on the animation element whenever the 'next' button is clicked.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maxflex/ym2f50pq/14/

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response. Hopefully my question made sense. I am going to incorporate  this into the website straight away, and fingers crossed I don't have any issues implementing this. The website has more complexities so If I get stuck, would you mind assisting me? @QuinnDaley